# Is a class C private IP address range (or even class A or B) both theoretical and practical or is it just theoretical?

Tags: networking, router, ipv4

My confusion is that, if we were to take, for example, a class C private IP range, it allows 254 hosts. Is this the theoretical amount or is it actually possible to have 254 hosts?

I'd assume having 254 hosts on a home network would surely slow down or stop the network from functioning correctly, or am I missing something?

Comment: Network classes are dead, killed in 1993 by RFCs 1517, 1519, and 1519, which defined CIDR (_Classless_ Inter-Domain Routing). Modern networks do not use network classes. Please let them rest in peace.

Comment: Relax, I got you the first time, that wasn't the point of the question

Comment: @RonMaupin, there is no difference between a Class C and a VLSM of 255.255.255.0. Class-full addressing schemes are far from dead, they are just subsummed in a more flexible scheme. now if we were talking about routing, I might be with you, but...

Comment: @FrankThomas, network classes were defined by the first bits of the address. That has absolutely no bearing on modern networking. Modern networking uses _Classless_ Inter-Domain Routing, allowing what used to be a full network class to be split among multiple ASes. VLSM is used with CIDR, and there is no trace of network classes anymore.

Comment: ever checkout RFC1918?

Comment: @FrankThomas, "_there is no difference between a Class C and a VLSM of 255.255.255.0._" That is patently false. The definition of a Class C network address is an address that started with the first three bits as `110`. (Class A started with `0`, Class B started with `10`, Class C started with `110`, Class D started with `1110`, and Class E started with `1111`). Each class A to C had a _default_ mask, but `10.0.0.0` with mask `255.255.255.0` was still a Class A network.

Comment: @FrankThomas, yes, but it says something interesting about _pre-CIDR_ notation: "_We will refer to the first block as "24-bit block", the second as
   "20-bit block", and to the third as "16-bit" block. Note that (in
   pre-CIDR notation) the first block is nothing but a single class A
   network number, while the second block is a set of 16 contiguous
   class B network numbers, and third block is a set of 256 contiguous
   class C network numbers._" The classes are based on the first bits of the address, not a mask.

Comment: The big value to CIDR is Route Aggregation (supernetting). in terms of address schemes, the network bit and host bit count have always been emphasised over the first byte of the address, with the exception of ASIC design (once again, routing). there is not and will never be an actual network for 156.0.0.0/8 though that is a valid aggregate for a routing table.  in terms of IP address schemes, if it quacks like a duck...

Comment: @FrankThomas, there are networks like `56.57.58.0/24` (_not_ Class C networks). RFC 791, Internet Protocol:  "_There are three formats or classes of internet addresses: in class a, the high order bit is zero, the next 7 bits are the network, and the last 24 bits are the local address; in class b, the high order two bits are one-zero, the next 14 bits are the network and the last 16 bits are the local address; in class c, the high order three bits are one-one-zero, the next 21 bits are the network and the last 8 bits are the local address."_ RFCs 1517, 1518, and 1519 killed that.

Comment: @FrankThomas, in fact, having been a network engineer for more than 30 years (pre-CIDR through CIDR), one of the interesting pre-employment questions I have seen is, "_How many Class C networks can you make out of `10.0.0.0/8`?_" The answer that fresh-out-of-school applicants give is always wrong. The correct answer is `0` because there are no more network classes, and any address in that range is an old Class A address. It weeds out those with no experience, and those that do not really understand IPv4 addressing.

Comment: @RonMaupin - you might split hairs as much as you wish, but "C" in the sense of any address range x.x.x.0 - x.x.x.255 is widely used in common technical speech, at least here.

Comment: @RonMaupin - not all teachers cover "historical" references like that.  I try to mention "what we called Class C in the old days but is really /24 in CIDR notation" in the classes I teach (Linux admin stuff), but I'm not sure if our intro to networking or cisco or windows server instructors do or not.  I do this simply because when I learned about it the Class system was still used, and I don't know what my students have/haven't read, learned elsewhere, etc.

Comment: @RonMaupin, since the classes are dead, isn't that question a bit counterproductive? Demanding the technically exact answer would weed out those who don't know long gone definitions (if they've somehow avoided hearing about classes at all), or those who instead have heard the colloquial meaning (class C == `/24`). (It'll also mark the questioner for either being a nitpicker and/or making trap questions on purpose; or as utterly confused, since after all, the premise of the question is faulty.)

Comment: @ilkkachu holy shit, the point of the question wasn't about class C specifically. I'm aware that we use CIDR now, but regardless, all I wanted to know was even if I was using a /25 subnet, would something like a home router even support having 126 hosts/subnet.

Comment: @TimalPeramune, ahh, I didn't mean your question! Only the "interesting pre-employment question" Ron mentioned in their [comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1334492/is-a-class-c-private-ip-address-range-or-even-class-a-or-b-both-theoretical-an?noredirect=1#comment1995418_1334492).

Answer (score 44, accepted):

To start with, classful addressing has not been used since the mid-90s. **Everything** uses CIDR now, which allows splitting an IPv4 address space into any size from a `/32` (2^(32-32) = 1 address) to `/0` (2^(32-0) addresses). The corresponding *size* for an (ancient) class C network would be a `/24` subnet in CIDR.

From a theoretical point of view, you can have networks of any size (that is a power of two). Of course, as you've correctly guessed, you will run into practical issues at some point, so we have to put some design effort into our networks.

---

Now, routers generally don't care how many addresses are in a single subnet. They'll forward them to the correct destination all the same. Where you might run into problems at the routing level is if you have *too many* subnets - we've been splitting subnets smaller and smaller to deal with IPv4 exhaustion, so where a company might have been able to purchase a single contiguous `/28` of 14 usable addresses in the past, they might need to purchase two separate `/29`s of 6 usable addresses each now.

What used to be a single `/16` (originally assigned as a class B some 30 years ago) might now be split into 1000 `/26`s, which means 1000 more entries in routing tables. Do this a few (thousand) times and your tables are now full. This has caused [major outages](http://bgphelp.com/2017/01/01/bgpsize/) before, and will likely do so again.

This only really matters with publicly routable addresses on internet core routers, which have to know the route to every network. Your home "router" is just going to forward everything via its default route and let your ISP deal with it. This is also largely irrelevant for private addresses, which are by definition not publicly routable.

---

The other potential issue you mention applies below the routing level, within a single subnet. Where you might run into issues here is if your *broadcast domain* is too big. While a broadcast domain is not necessarily the same thing as a subnet, for most (especially consumer/home) purposes it is the same.

When your broadcast domain gets too big, you can run into issues: your OS's ARP tables might overflow (~256 by default in Windows, ~1024 by default in Linux, but tunable on both). This means your OS starts forgetting which MAC address an IP address corresponds to, and needs to discover it again by sending an ARP request ... which is broadcast to every host. With too many hosts, a good chunk of your network bandwidth is taken by ARP requests and responses.

Also, your network switches (often built into consumer routers as the 4 "LAN" ports) can get a bit unhappy with too many hosts because their fowarding tables (based on MAC addresses, not IP addresses) are only of a fixed size, and they can start "forgetting" which port to forward to.

Luckily (or by design?), these issues tend to appear somewhere north of 256 hosts, so 254 in a single subnet probably won't run into them. They *are* a reason you're generally supposed to route between `/24`s rather than using, say, a single `/16`.

---

One other advantage of assigning a whole `/24` is so we have some spare room for DHCP-assigned addresses. Most home networks these days don't have a static address assigned to each host - they are instead chosen by a DHCP server and reserved for a period of time, so e.g. your phone doesn't get a new address every time it disconnects for a second. When your network is *almost* full, you force the DHCP server to start recycling addresses sooner.

Most DHCP servers on consumer routers default to an address pool of only 100 addresses, so you will never reach 254 without either adjusting the pool size or assigning static addresses.

---

At the end of the day, while we have issues with IPv4 exhaustion at the global level, there's absolutely no shortage of *private* addresses (which have three large ranges, a `/8`, a `/12` and a `/16`, to play with -- that can contain over 65000 `/24`s). There's little reason to try conserving them, so no one bothers going smaller than a `/24`.

And, if you want to, you certainly can have 254 hosts active on a `/24`. Most consumer routers/switches and OSes will even handle it fine for the most part, though some tweaking (esp. DHCP) may be required.

Answer (score 16):

They are real/concrete limits, not just theoretical. There's nothing about IP addressing schemes that "pushes the boundaries" of the technology, so it works exactly as advertised.

A Class-C uses 8 bits for host addressing, so 
00000000 - 11111111 is the actual range (0-255 or 256 ordinal values). of those the top and bottom values are reserved for the broadcast and the route ID, leaving you with 254 available addresses.

IP addressing cares not a whit for your performance. That is entirely determined by the hardware and software you have running your network, and nothing to do with IP addressing schemes.

Comment: I like your answer the best.  In my next breath I would emphasize that with 250 addresses you will quickly find out the limits of home equipment.  All the broadcast and general junk flying around seems to overwhelm a lot of consumer grade equipment.  The original question seems very relevant and in that situation you would want to proactively deal with it as opposed to allowing everyone on the same subnet.  Even in an ipv6 scenario this seems to be the case with the home router I got at the dollar store in the bargain bin.

Comment: The question already indicates understanding of the basic address structure. His question is more about practical capacity of the hardware.